# Which is the best way to validate the parameters received by a function

Tags: javascript

```
Create: function (title, text, orientation, trigger, layout) {
        $(this).attr
    },
```

The trigger parameter must receive one of two very specific words: 'hover' or 'click' and I can't think of a good way to ease the implementation of this function.

I did think of some solutions:

1. I can try to validate the parameter once already inside in the function and return a 'console.info' right after breaking the execution in case a wrong parameter has been sent, informing the developer of his mistake
2. I could create a ENUM and provide it as an interface for the developer (which would still make the developer have to read it in order to use it properly)
3. Occurred me while typing this post that I could just set standard values for the options, hence they're optional.

I just don't know which one is the best approach in a situation like this. Can I assume that the developer that is willing to use the code MUST read the code to find the best way to implement it or (as I suppose) I should be concerned with validations like the ones I described? Also which one is the best?

Comment: Assuming your intent is to create something publicly available, it should have a published API which defines the parameters and should not require the developer to read the code.

Comment: Are you wondering about how to validate the values for *one* specific parameter or how to handle so many parameters. Personally, if there are more than 3 parameters and if there can be optional ones, I would let the function accept an object instead. Using default values is good IMO.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I'm sorry if it sounded like i was willing to publish it somewhere. It's more a conceptual question than a real problem, but i am developing in a company and i want to use the best practices since other fellow developers will use the code as well.

Comment: @FelixKling The main question is wether i should or not care about preventing a third person from missusing the constructor, informing it trough the console, or just handling the mistakes myself inside the code.

Comment: @Hoffmann You might find it odd but i never thought of that. I absolutely agree that consoles and alerts shouldn't be in released versions. In this case i was assuming i could use the 'console.info' as some sort of Intelissense to teach how the developer should implement the function, but in the other hand it's almost the same as not validating and commenting the code

Comment: @v1n1akabozo I never actually tested with console.info, but console.log makes the script crash in IE, I guess what you actually want is more of how to handle this error, I will expand on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing straight up with strings is a common practice in javascript. ENUM-like structures, although easy to implement, are usually not very used because you either have to define your ENUM-like as globals or do something like:

```
application.enums.myObject.hover= 1;
application.enums.myObject.click= 2;

myObject= new application.constructors.MyObject();
myObject.create(title, text, orientation, application.enums.myObject.hover, layout)
```

In this manner only application is global, but typing application.enums.myObject is a pain.

**How to handle the error:**

Option 1: throw an exception:

```
Create: function (title, text, orientation, trigger, layout) {
        if (trigger !== "hover" && trigger !== "click") {
            throw "error: invalid parameter trigger";
        }
    },
```

This will crash your script unless you have a catch clause somewhere. In some cases crashing the party is better than not providing a way to know what is wrong. If you intend on catching these exceptions (instead of letting them just crash the script) I recommed doing it properly by making classes for your errors and such.

Option 2: Return null.

```
Create: function (title, text, orientation, trigger, layout) {
        if (trigger !== "hover" && trigger !== "click") {
            return null;
        }
    },
```

This approach works better if you are going to use the return value of the function. When debugging you will see "object has no property named X" error when trying to use the return value (or your value will be coerced into the "null" string if you use it as such).

Option 3: Quietly ignore the error and do nothing. Either your script will crash on its own or it will do nothing. Not recommended

Observations:

1 - do not use the console object in production code. It's not part of the standard and IE does not expose it to the web page unless you open the developer console

2 - do not start your function names with an upper case letter unless it's a function that should be called with the 'new' keyword (ie a constructor function).

Comment: I agree with both statements, it's just that i'm not used with javascript and web-development so i don't know if i should be concerned with the implementation. Anyone that reads the function, once it's finished, should be able to know how to use it, so i don't know how far i must go with validations and pointing the mistakes of it's usage.

Comment: @v1n1akabozo answer updated with techniques to handle the error.

Comment: that was the kind of answer i was waiting for man, i appreciate it. Throwing an exception seems much better than using a console.info to prompt the error, and setting the return value to null is also pretty intuitive. Thanks